# How to add and load an object in a store using React Flux on component creation

Tags: reactjs, flux

#### Question

When I load a React Component, how I can add an object to a store, and then immediately load it into the component's state using the Flux pattern?

#### Background

I have a Flux store (`TableStore`) that manages objects called `Tables`, and React components called `TableList` and `TableEditor`.

The `TableList` component lists the tables in the store, and each item has an edit button that navigates to `/tables/editor/:tableId`, which loads the `TableEditor` component, and `TableEditor` gets the table from the store via the tableId in the URL.

`TableList` also has a "Create new table" button.  Which navigates to `/tables/editor/new`.  When this URL is loaded, I need to add a new `Table` to the store and then load it into `TableEditor`'s state.

Using the Flux pattern, components aren't supposed to call functions like this directly; they're supposed to call `Actions` which dispatch actions to the Store.  Unfortunately, if an action is called in a component's `getInitialState()`, the function in the store is executed *before* `componentWillMount()` is executed in the component, and the component misses the `change` event from the store, so my `TableEditor` component doesn't load the table from `TableStore`.

I assume this is a pretty common need, so there must be a standard way of getting around this (I hope).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making a bit of confusion with the flux pattern.

> When I load a React Component, how I can add an object to a store, and
>   then immediately load it into the component's state using the Flux
>   pattern?

**how I can add an object to a store?**

You should always add an object to store emitting a new create action. The store register itself to the dispatcher to listen to actions. When a action is dispatched, an handler is called to perform that action. This is the only way to mutate the state of a store. For example, in your case, the view should emit a `TABLE_CREATE` action. The `TableStore` should list for table `TABLE_CREATE` and save the new table. A bit of code:

*Table List View*

```
onSave: function(table) {
 TableActions.create(table);
}
```

*Table Actions*

```
var TodoActions = {
 create: function(text) {
   AppDispatcher.handleTableAction({
   actionType: TableConstants.TABLE_CREATE,
   table:table
 });
}
```

*Table Store*

```
  switch(action.actionType) {
    case TableConstants.TABLE_CREATE:
      text = action.table();
      if (!isEmpty(table)) {
        create(table);
        TableStore.emitChange();
      }
      break;
```

As you can see, the above code is following the flux pattern:

```
 VIEW --(Action)--> DISPATCHER --(Action)--> STORE
```

**Immediately load it into the component's state using the Flux pattern?**

You fetch it directly from the store. We can read the stores from the views as we are not performing any state mutation. State mutation should be propagate by means of actions. Therefore, your component should use the function `getInitialState` to read the value from the `TableStore`. Probably, you need to use some sort of `id`. Code:

```
getInitialState() {
 return { 
  table : TableStore.getTableById(id)
 }
}
```

---

According to what you wrote, you have a store which contains all tables. 
When a user clicks the button create a new action should be dispatched to the table store in order to add the new table to the store. The table store should be listening for this action. Now, the user is likely redirect to the editor page where he can edit the newly table. The edit table view fetches the value from the store in the `getInitialState` and reders the edit. Make sense?

Comment: I actually started doing that approach before I posted this, and ran into a similar problem later on, but more importantly, I realized that saving a bookmark to /tables/edit/new and going directly to that link should have the same behavior.

Comment: @dfoverdx I don't understand. Have you already implemented as I suggested? If so, I don't understand the problem. My code examples are based on todo in the flux website.

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try is to always keep a new and empty table object (or just a 'free' table ID) in your table store.

Couple the NEW button (or whatever it is that user does to create a new table) to a `/tables/editor/:tableId` that holds your new empty Id.

That way, your do not need a fancy redirect from `/new` to `/:tableId` etc.